# Wireshark Signalling Point Codes resolution with host files is not working

Tags: wireshark

I recently found out that the following ticket has been implemented and closed:
https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7592

So following the guideline on how to include point code names in the host files, I created the following entry:

2-567 MSS_999

But after reloading the .pcap file, the Address remained 567 in the trace. Every other IP address I have in this host file is correctly resolved, meaning the file itself and the preferences should be correct. Only the point codes are not resolved.

I am using the latest version 2.2.6 so I am wondering which release contains this solution?

Regards,
Tamas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available in version 2.2.6, and since it's an enhancement, it won't ever be back-ported to the 2.2 branch.

This only works with the latest development version of Wireshark.  You can try it using one of the recent Wireshark automated builds, which you can download from [here](https://www.wireshark.org/download/automated/).  Make sure you enable SS7 point code name resolution via: *Edit -> Preferences -> Name Resolution -> Resolve SS7 PCs*.

Comment: Thank you very much Christopher, your solution resolved my problem!